# Integrating GiroPay and SOFORT via Stripe

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I tried to integrate the other offered payments offered by [stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/sources). I followed the docs but it seems I overread something (read everthing like 10 times).

First I activated the payment methods.

I added the library: `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>`

I created a Stripe client: `var stripe = Stripe('pk_live_512dfvL8d63Kcs9d5Lsp548c6Sp');` (tried this with both test and publishable key)

I added an instance of Elements: `var elements = stripe.elements();` (Not using it though)

Depending on the choosen payment something else gets triggered. Well here is my code:

```
function buyingProcess() {
  console.log(choosenPaymentMethod);
  if (choosenPaymentMethod == "mastervisa") {
    // This works like a charm
  } else if (choosenPaymentMethod == "giropay") {
    stripe.createSource({
      type: 'giropay',
      amount: 1099,
      currency: 'eur',
      owner: {
        name: 'Jenny Rosen',
      },
      redirect: {
        return_url: 'https://shop.example.com/crtA6B28E1',
      },
    }).then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      // handle result.error or result.source
    });
  }
}
```

The last `console.log` function shows me the source object. While using the test key `console.log(result.error)` stated out, that I have to use the publishable key.

Thanks for any help. I wrote the Stripe Team. yesterday at this time but I apreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeing a source object in your console, then you have successfully created a source!  The next step is to set up a webhook endpoint, and listen for a `source.chargeable` event.

Once you have received that your customer has authorized the source to be charged, and you can create a charge on your server using your secret key:
https://stripe.com/docs/sources/best-practices#charge-creation

You can delete `var elements = stripe.elements();` as you don't need Elements to create sources, just the Stripe.js library.